# Receive data from check boxes in different Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

I have several checkboxes in my Activity_Main.XML similar to as follows

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Video"
        android:id="@+id/Video"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/VideoCheck"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

Now on a different activity I want the state of this checkbox to be displayed, for ease of use I have set up the code so it will change the text or a text label. Code in my MenuActivity.java is as follows

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.VideoCheck:
            if (checked) {
                TextView MyTextLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Test1);
                MyTextLabel.setText("Video");
            }
            else
            {
                TextView MyTextLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Test1);
                MyTextLabel.setText("No Video");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Worth saying the text label on the XML display is called MyTextLabel. I think the problem is because the Checkboxes are set up to call "onCheckboxClicked" but that checkbox clicked part is not in the Activity native to that set up.

Essentially the first page(activity_main.xml, MainActivity.Java) of my app has the checkboxes, then a button takes the user to the second page (activity_menu.xml, MenuActivity.java) has the Label set to change depending on the state of the checkboxes on the first page.

I appreciate this is explained horrendously but please ask any question you may have.

Comment: findViewById (int id) Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle). So you can't access the view of MainActivity from MenuActivity

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the state of the checkbox in the `Intent` you use to start the second activity. See [Build an Intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent) for details. Then in the second activity, you need to extract the checkbox state from the received intent. See [Receive an Intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#ReceiveIntent).

Note that I am assuming that you already know how to create an `Intent` to start an `Activity`. If not, you should read [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).